# Are there Zoll pancakes?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

How flat (flat in pancake-style, not in curvature 0-style), in some extrinsic intuitive measure, can a Zoll surface of revolution (embedded in Euclidean three-space) be?

I don't want to impose a measure of "flatness", but, for example, we can (1) normalize the area of the surface to be $4\pi$ and take the extrinsic distance between the poles as a measure of "flatness" or (2) consider the Hausdorff distance between the surface and a flat disc.

If the surface is convex, then it cannot be too flat: fixing the length of the closed geodesics to $2\pi$ (or the area to $4\pi$), the distance between the poles must be greater than $\pi -2$ (really easy exercise, but this quantity is not optimal).

Comment: Now, instead, does it make sense?... ^_o

Comment: In a loose way, yes ... Oh, I forgot to add that the surface is a surface of revolution embedded in Euclidean three-space.

Comment: (An aside: An image of a Zoll surface of revolution can be found at the question, "[How to draw a Zoll surface?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/150559/6094).")

Comment: It isn't clear to me if the extrinsic distance from a point to its opposite pole is positive. Keep in mind that Zoll surfaces can have negative curvature on open sets, so not convex.

Comment: Ben, you change from point to pole in the wording of your comment. Could you please clarify? Do you mean that the Zoll surface could have self-intersections and we could think of the distance between the poles (fixed points of the circle action) as negative?

Comment: As I said in the question, I'd gladly consider other ways of measuring flatness (Hausdorff distance to a plane disc ?).

Comment: @BenMcKay: "can have negative curvature on open sets"---May I ask: Do you know if this is still possible for a Zoll *surface of revolution*?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke:  Yes you can have negative curvature for a Zoll surface of revolution.  Have a look at the examples described in Chapter 4, Section C (particularly, see Fig 4.25d-e) of A. Besse, *Manifolds all of whose geodesics are closed*.  (Also, take a look at the comment at the top of page 107.)

Comment: I can't tell you the answer but I think it should exist;) By this I mean that Zoll surfaces of revolution are given by explicit formulas, using any odd function on the interval [-1,1] you have a Zoll metric. So probably the curvature can be calculated then. What do you think?

Comment: @Olga, very roughly speaking the way one constructs Zoll surfaces of revolution is that one is free to choose one of the hemispheres (let's say the north hemisphere, the equator being a closed planar geodesic) and you compensate accordingly with the other hemisphere to make the surface Zoll.  One would  really have understand this "north-south" construction better (or at least better than I do).