# Some facts about cut-locus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Let $M$ be a 2-dimensional closed Riemmanian manifold diffeomorphic  to $S^2$.

S.B.Myers says "the cut-locus of every point $x\in M$ is a finite tree."

> 1. How the set of point  can be a tree? What are the edges?
> 2. Is $p$ an element of $\operatorname{cut-locus}(p)$?

I can not find any paper of Myers in this case.
Thanks!

Comment: Dear azita, I changed the tags and the formatting of your question, I hope you don't mind. Perhaps you could add a reference for the quote? Also, re 2: The answer is surely no, by definition of the cut-locus?

Comment: Dear @Mark Grant, it is always a good idea to add a top level tag (these are tags with a two letter code, such as 'at.algebraic-topology') whenever possible. See the meta thread http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/frequently-asked-questions-about-tagging-on-mathoverflow/ for some more information.

Comment: Dear Rikardo .thank you. when I was studying paper about algebraic-topology meet this case.

Answer (score 8):

I think Myers only considered analytic metrics, see his papers "Connections between differential geometry and topology I and II", Duke Math. J. 1 (1935), 376-391, and 2 (1936), 95-102.

For arbitrary metrics on $S^2$ the cut locus is indeed a tree. This can be deduced from e.g. in [Shiohama and Tanaka, Cut loci and distance spheres on Alexandrov surfaces] who work in the (more general) settings of Alexandrov spaces homeomorphic to surfaces and prove that the cut locus is a local tree.
(This paper is available online, search by title). Specializing to the case when the surface is a Riemannian sphere we observe:

1. The complement to the cut locus is a 2-disk.
2. If the cut locus contains an embedded circle, then by Jordan curve theorem the circle separates $S^2$ into two disks, and by part 1 one of the disks must lie in the cut locus, so the cut locus cannot be  local tree.

One should be careful with what is meant by a local tree. By a result of Gluck and Singer [Scattering of Geodesic Fields II, Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 110, No. 2 (Sep., 1979), pp. 205-225] there is a positively curved Riemannian metric on $S^2$, in fact a convex surface of revolution, for which the cut locus cannot be triangulated, so it is definitely not a finite tree.

For recent works in this area see papers of Itoh, e.g. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.1758 and references therein.

Answer (score 2):

If you will excuse me substituting a polyhedron for the Riemannian manifold
(imagine rounding the vertices),
this figure shows how the cut locus (red) from source $x$ is a tree.
(The green arcs are equidistant from $x$.)

     [image: 2x1x1Box]

     <sub>(Figure from [Discrete and Computational Geometry](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/DCG/))</sub>

Concerning, "What are the edges?": They are geodesics, such that there are two
distinct shortest paths from $x$ to every interior point of an edge of the cut locus.
Points of the cut locus of degree $k$ have $k$ distinct shortest paths from $x$.

Comment: And see [this earlier MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/a/37652/6094) for an image of a cut locus on a Zoll surface.

Comment: Dear josef.I see your answer. this figure must be useful .i need thinking about it.thank you so much.